# Loop is not breaking - JSON parsing with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

This is my JSON array:

```
[
      [ 36,
        100,
        "The 3n + 1 problem",
         56717,
         0,
         1000000000,
         0,
         6316,
         0,
         0,
         88834,
         0,
         45930,
         0,
         46527,
         5209,
         200860,
         3597,
         149256,
         3000,
         1
      ],
      [
         ........
      ],
      [
         ........
      ],
         .....// and almost 5000 arrays like above
]
```

I want to need the first four values of eah array and skip rest of the values like:

```
36 100 "The 3n + 1 problem" 56717
```

And this is the code I wrote so far:

```
reader.beginArray();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
         System.out.println(reader.nextInt() + " " + reader.nextInt()
                            + " " + reader.nextString() + " "
                            + reader.nextInt());
         for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            reader.skipValue();
         }
         reader.skipValue();
    }
    reader.endArray();
    System.out.println("loop is break"); // this is not printed as the inner loop is not breaking
}
reader.endArray();
reader.close();
```

And it is printing as I expected:

```
36 100 "The 3n + 1 problem" 56717
.................................
..................................
1049 10108 The Mosquito Killer Mosquitos 49
1050 10109 Solving Systems of Linear Equations 129
1051 10110 Light, more light 9414
1052 10111 Find the Winning Move 365
```

This is working but the inner loop is not breaking correctly. What is the wrong with my code? what I missed there so that my code is not working?

**Edit: (Solution)**
I ended up with this solution:

```
reader.beginArray();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                reader.beginArray(); 
                // read and parse first four elements, checking hasNext() each time for robustness
                int a = reader.nextInt(); 
                int b = reader.nextInt();
                String c = reader.nextString();
                int d = reader.nextInt();
                System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
                while (reader.hasNext())
                    reader.skipValue();
                reader.endArray();
            } 
            reader.endArray();
```

Comment: Could you please specify the libraries you are using to read json in Java.

Comment: It is `GSON` by google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to call skipValue() or next* if hasNext() returns false. The [GSON documentation](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html) recommends accumulating values first. A variation on that theme is:

```
reader.beginArray();
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    int position;
    int a, b, d; // stores your parsed values
    String c; // stores your parsed values
    reader.beginArray(); 
    // read and parse first four elements, checking hasNext() each time for robustness
    for (position = 0; position < 4 && reader.hasNext(); ++ position) {
        if (position == 0) a = reader.nextInt(); 
        else if (position == 1) b = reader.nextInt();
        else if (position == 2) c = reader.nextString();
        else if (position == 3) d = reader.nextInt();
    } 
    // if position < 4 then there weren't enough values in array.
    if (position == 4) { // correctly read 
        System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d);
    }
    // skip rest of array, regardless of number of values
    while (reader.hasNext())
        reader.skipValue();
    reader.endArray();
} 
reader.endArray();
```

Note that there are plenty of other ways to parse those first 4 values, use whatever makes sense for your situation (e.g. store them in a List first, or store them as Strings then parse later, or whatever you want -- the point is, do not make assumptions on the number of elements in the array, stick to the rules and use hasNext() before reading each element).

Comment: Sir, it's perfectly working? I have a pretty big Json feed and I was parsing json with android built-in `JSONparser`. For increasing performance I am working now with `GSON` now. Do you think above approach is the fastest possible way? or is there any way for further optimization?

Comment: There's not much you can do to optimize it. The above code uses GSON as per its documentation, which is the best you can do. The time-consuming part is GSON's parser code itself, which you have no control over. In any case, you are not asking the right question. Do not optimize prematurely. First get your code working, *then* if it does not meet your performance requirements, find your bottlenecks and start thinking about optimizations.

Comment: Thank you for some great conceptual tips also :)